# Need help understanding parameter passing to programs

Tags: shell

Assum p is a program and v is a variable containing the string " a b c"

am I correct by saying that

p $v will run p with **three** parameters, that are a, b and c (so argc is 4 for a c program)

p "$v"  will run p with **one** parameters, that is " a b c" (so argc is 2 for a c program)

Answer (score 1):

A quick test would've told you this. I created the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PARAM1="$1"
PARAM2="$2"
PARAM3="$3"

echo "PARAM1: $PARAM1"
echo "PARAM2: $PARAM2"
echo "PARAM3: $PARAM3"
```

And the output for both cases is:

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ ./params.sh a b c
PARAM1: a
PARAM2: b
PARAM3: c
mtak@frisbee:~$ ./params.sh "a b c"
PARAM1: a b c
PARAM2: 
PARAM3:
```

So yes, you are correct in your statement.

Comment: I think this is incorrect - specifically you are not first setting the values a b c into a variable - and this changes the behaviour.

Comment: @davidgo: Huh? Storing the values in variables is exactly what the script _does._

Comment: @grawity the way I read the question is that the OP has a variable ($v) which he is wanting to pass to the script.  ie calling v="a b c"; ./p $v   as opposed to ./p a b c - and the output is different.

Comment: After testing with v='a b c' and running./params.sh $v I get the first output. I was surprised that the shell does "break" parameters after substituting $v with its value based on spaces, instead of considering $v as one parameter. However the substitution doesn't look recursive, so if v was defined as v='$w' it will not proceed to substitute $w, nor the singles quotes if present inside $v will protect space "breaking"

Answer (score 1):

the way to answer this program is to write a trivial shell script (called "p"):

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Arg 0: ".$0
echo "Arg 1: ".$1
echo "Arg 2: ".$2
echo "Arg 3: ".$3
```

You can then play with it and see what it produces, and you will find the following:

(Remember to run v="a b c" before you play with it, and pass p $v (rather then p 1 2 3 - which will behave differently)

argc=2 in both cases - which makes sense.  The quotes on the command line mean to group all the parameters into 1 option.

If you need to have a single variable with multiple parameters, you can always split these up in bash quite simply, for example using  a script like

```
#! /bin/bash

i=0
for each in $@
do
       a[i]=$each
       i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done

echo ${a[0]}
echo ${a[1]}
echo ${a[2]}
echo ${a[3]}
```

Will split the variables into elements in an array ($a)

Comment: I think you may be wrong, I tested with a trivial C program, if you say define v='a b c' in the the calling shell script, then p $v (p is a C program) will have argc=4 (a,b,c and program's name), so really$v is not considered as one parameter.